# Angular is adding an empty array to a 2D array - where/why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I'm having a bit of a weird problem and there are now 2 people in my office completely stumped by this (so I hope it's not something embarrassingly obvious!).

As an overview, we have a SQLite database that could contain any number of tables, each with any number of rows or columns. We want to display this data in a page in an Electron app.

We have an Angular page in our Electron app (with Express/Node as a backend) which makes some calls to an Express endpoint (which gets data from the SQLite db) and we end up with two 2D arrays of data - one for the table headers ($scope.tableHeaders) and one for the table content ($scope.documentsList).

The code for the calls is below:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/tableCount').then(function (res) {
    if (res.data.numberoftables) {
        $scope.count = res.data.numberoftables;
        var i;
        $scope.documentsList = new Array();
        $scope.tableHeaders = new Array();

        for (i = 1; i <= $scope.count; i++) {
            var tableNo = i;
            //loop through tables
            ***$http.get('http://localhost:3000/doclist/' + tableNo).then(function (resDocs) {
                //get table content
                if (resDocs.data) {
                    ***$scope.documentsList.push(resDocs.data);
                }
            });

            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/tableColumns/' + tableNo).then(function (resHeads) {
                //get table headers
                if (resHeads.data) {
                    $scope.tableHeaders.push(resHeads.data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Just for fun, here's our HTML:

```
<div id="documentTables">
    <div ng-repeat="tableID in getNumberArray(count)">
        <table st-table="documentsList[tableID]" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr st-safe-src="tableHeaders[tableID]">
                    <th ng-repeat="col in tableHeaders[tableID]">
                        {{col}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr st-safe-src="tableHeaders[tableID]" colspan="{{tableHeaders[tableID].length}}">
                    <th colspan="1" ng-repeat="col in tableHeaders[tableID]">
                        <input id="{{col + 'searchbox' + tableID}}" st-search="col" placeholder="{{col}}" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr st-safe-src="documentsList[tableID]" ng-repeat="document in documentsList[tableID]">
                    <td ng-repeat="col in tableHeaders[tableID]">
                        {{document[col].value}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="{{tableHeaders[tableID].length}}" class="text-center">
                        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem we're coming across is that no actual data is displayed in the tables. Somewhere between the starred lines (***) in the JS above, an empty array for each table is added. So if we have two tables in our database, we end up with `documentsList = Array[4]` with `documentsList[0]` and `documentsList[1]` being empty arrays. Why/where would this be happening, and how can I fix it?

Note - if you'd like to test this out without our endpoints, try out these variables:

```
$scope.count = 2;
$scope.tableHeaders = [["TabNo", "Document", "PageNumber", "Date"],["TabNo", "Document", "PageNumber"]];
$scope.documentsList = [];
$scope.documentsList.push(JSON.parse('[{"idANX":1,"pathANX":"Product Overview.pdf","isHeaderANX":1,"isExcludedANX":0,"isNotHyperlinkedANX":0,"isSubHeaderANX":0,"HyperlinkedColumnANX":1,"TabNo":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"1"},"Document":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"Product Overview.pdf","isLastCell":false,"value":"Product Overview"},"PageNumber":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"1 - 2"},"Date":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":true,"value":"18 August 2015"}},{"idANX":2,"pathANX":"Spec.pdf","isHeaderANX":0,"isExcludedANX":0,"isNotHyperlinkedANX":0,"isSubHeaderANX":0,"HyperlinkedColumnANX":1,"TabNo":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"2"},"Document":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"Spec.pdf","isLastCell":false,"value":"Spec"},"PageNumber":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"3 - 4"},"Date":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":true,"value":"1 April 2015"}}]');
$scope.documentsList.push(JSON.parse('[{"idANX":1,"pathANX":"Product Overview.pdf","isHeaderANX":0,"isExcludedANX":0,"isNotHyperlinkedANX":0,"isSubHeaderANX":0,"HyperlinkedColumnANX":1,"TabNo":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"1"},"Document":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"Product Overview.pdf","isLastCell":false,"value":"Product Overview"},"PageNumber":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"1 - 2"}},{"idANX":2,"pathANX":"Spec.pdf","isHeaderANX":0,"isExcludedANX":0,"isNotHyperlinkedANX":0,"isSubHeaderANX":0,"HyperlinkedColumnANX":1,"TabNo":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"2"},"Document":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"Spec.pdf","isLastCell":false,"value":"Spec"},"PageNumber":{"colspan":0,"rowspan":0,"hyperlinkedDoc":"","isLastCell":false,"value":"3 - 4"}}]');

$scope.getNumberArray = function (num) {
    var n = new Array(num);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        n[i] = i;
    }
    return n;
}

$scope.rowClass = function (row) {
    if (row.isSubHeaderANX == 1) {
        return 'subheader';
    } else if (row.isHeaderANX == 1) {
        return 'header';
    }
    else { return 'doctablerow'; }
}
```

<s>Also pagination and filtering don't work but that's an issue for when our table actually contains data.</s>

Edit: Probably should have mentioned that this is using [angular-smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)

Comment: Have you verified that `http://localhost:3000/doclist/' + tableNo` is not returning empty arrays?

Comment: @Fusion89k Yep, it's returning exactly what I'm expecting it to, and the `.push(resDocs.data)` is *only* hit when I can see that the right data is being returned in the Network tab in Chrome.

Comment: Also the documentsList array already has the two empty elements *before* `.push(...)` is called...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at how asynchronous requests and promises works. To make your code run you could do this: var promises = []; // Creates an array to store the promises

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/tableCount').then(function (res) {
    if (res.data.numberoftables) {
        $scope.count = res.data.numberoftables;
        var i;
        $scope.documentsList = new Array();
        $scope.tableHeaders = new Array();
        var promises = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= $scope.count; i++) {
            var tableNo = i;
            $scope.getHttp(i).then(function(resp){
            $scope.documentsList.push(resolutions[0]);
            $scope.tableHeaders.push(resolutions[1]);
            });
        }
    }
});

$scope.getHttp = function(tableNo){

var promise;
             promise = $http({
                url:'http://localhost:3000/doclist/' + tableNo,
                method:'get'
            });
             promises.push(promise);
             promise = $http({
                url:'http://localhost:3000/tableColumns/' + tableNo,
                method:'get'
            });
            promises.push(promise);
            return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Make the changes accordingly. I did not test it because dont have complete controller.But for sure, if you are looping http, make sure promises are stored.

Comment: I've just tried this out and it's still happening I'm afraid. Might it be something about the declaration of the arrays?